# Resend frames of message without copy

Tags: zeromq

### Question:

Can I initialize a new message with **part** of another message without copying?  Modifying the message in place to drop the first few frames would also work.

### Scenario:

I'm using the ROUTER-REQ pattern for a load balancing implementation.  The REQ end sends a message to the ROUTER which prepends the identity and delimiter frame to the message.  After my application uses that first frame to push the identity of the worker into an idle list, it needs to forward the final frame(s) of the message onto a PUB socket.  Those final frames may be very large, and after extracting that first identity frame, I no longer need the rest of the received message, only to forward it on.  This seems like a good place for zero-copy; I just need to drop those first two frames which were inserted by the ROUTER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but I think you can, I would try it with

using `zmq_msg_copy`, according to the [man page](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-msg-copy).

> The implementation may choose not to physically copy the message
>   content, rather to share the underlying buffer between src and dest.

I don't know why the man page uses "may choose", looking into the [code](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq3-x/blob/master/src/msg.cpp#L172) I think it does all the time.

Here when I'm talking about message I mean "message part". so when you create your multipart message, you just zero-copy the necessary parts (frames)

Which binding do you use?

Comment: I'll either use the C API directly or a custom D binding to the C API.  I hadn't realized that frames used individual `zmq_msg_t` objects and assumed that using `zmq_msg_copy` would copy all frames making up a logical message.